# C++ compiler raises an error in one function call in one source file but not in another source file with the same function call

Tags: c++

I have two C++ source files that have the following snippet in their code.

```
...
unsigned int triangleVaos[] = { 0, 0 };
unsigned int triangleVbos[] = { 0, 0 };
unsigned int numTriangleVaos = sizeof(triangleVaos) / sizeof(*triangleVaos);
unsigned int numTriangleVbos = sizeof(triangleVbos) / sizeof(*triangleVbos);
for (int index = 0; index < numTriangleVaos; index++) {
    unsigned int* triangleVao = &triangleVaos[index];
    glGenVertexArrays(1, triangleVaos);

    glBindVertexArray(triangleVao);
    ...
...
```

I am compiling the source files with:

```
g++ -g \
    -std=c++11 \
    -I include/ \
    -o src/1-getting-started/exer-hello-triangle-3 \
    src/1-getting-started/exer-hello-triangle-3.cpp src/utils/glad.c \
    -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi -ldl;
```

When I compile the first source file, everything goes fine. However, whenever I compile the second source file, I get the following error message:

```
src/1-getting-started/exer-hello-triangle-3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/1-getting-started/exer-hello-triangle-3.cpp:156:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int*’ to ‘GLuint {aka unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
     glBindVertexArray(triangleVao);
```

This forces me to modify the snippet in the second source file to:

```
...
for (int index = 0; index < numTriangleVaos; index++) {
    unsigned int* triangleVao = &triangleVaos[index];
    glGenVertexArrays(1, triangleVaos);

    glBindVertexArray(*triangleVao);
...
```

Compiling the second source file now succeeds.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `.c` files are compiled with different rules than `.cpp` files by g++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Both source files are `.cpp` files.

Comment: `src/utils/glad.c` ??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That file is not what I was referring to with "two source files". Nevertheless, I have already found the solution to my problem. I am posting an answer for this question in case someone stumbles upon this.

Comment: @hyde It is indeed clear. What baffled me before I figured what the problem was is that the first source file is able to compile when I was not passing a pointer to a `uint`, but not with the second source file.

Comment: Both calls are wrong. The first one passes the wrong type, and the second one is wrong when `index != 0` because you only initialize the first element of `triangleVaos` in the call to `glGenVertexArrays`.

Comment: @interjay, yes, the first one is indeed passing the wrong type. Actually, both source files are still wrong when calling to `glGenVertexArrays()`. Haha. Question: Am I only initializing the first element of `triangleVaos` in the call to `glGenVertexArrays()` because referring (what's the right term?) to `triangleVaos` only would give me the first element of that array?

Comment: `glGenVertexArrays(1, triangleVaos);` means to set one element of `triangleVaos`. Look up documentation for `glGenVertexArrays`.

Comment: Ohhh. I see, Thanks, @interjay!

Answer (score -1):

(This answer exists in case anyone might stumble upon this question.)

It turns out that I have erroneously set my compilation commands (I am using `make`). The compilation command for the first source file is set to compiling a different (but error-free) source file, which causes the compilation to succeed. The compilation command for the second source file is correctly set to compiling the second source file, which has errors, and thus, failing to compile.

The lesson here is to make sure your compilation commands are properly set to compile the files you intend to have compiled. A simple mistake that was overlooked can cause a huge problem later on.